# Issues after email service migration from POP to IMAP/AWS workmail

Tags: outlook, amazon-workmail

We have recently migrated email service from pop to AWS workmail (IMAP).

We are facing a number of issues which are listed below.

1. Unable to configure Workmail email client on Android devices as
   Exchange.
2. Unable to change Account type from POP to IMAP in Outlook.
3. When a new account is configured in outlook, it is taking too much time
   in synchronizing folders and new account.
4. Taking too much time in sending emails and mostly emails remain in
   outbox.
5. Multiple accounts in Outlook are showing email address as the account
   name on the left pane of Home tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix/solution of each issue.

1. Unable to configure Workmail email client on Android devices as
   Exchange.

For IOS devices AWS workmail is configured as Exchange account, but for Android devices, it is configured as Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync.
See full detail from workmail userguide [connect_android_device](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/mobile-start.html#connect_android_device)

2. Unable to change Account type from POP to IMAP in Outlook.

There is no way to change account type from POP to IMAP or vice-versa.

Follow below steps in outlook.

- File>>Open Export>>Export-Export existing email account as PST file.
- Delete existing Email Account from Outlook
- Configure New mail account as IMAP Account.
- File>>Open Export>>Import-Import Pst file again.

Below is a detailed Link to [Change Account type in Outlook](https://hostpapasupport.com/change-account-pop-imap-outlook-2013/)

3. When a new account is configured in outlook, it is taking too much time
   in synchronizing folders and new account.
4. Taking too much time in sending emails and mostly emails remain in
   outbox.

First-time account configuration will take time, as it will sync all emails and folders in outlook client (depending on the number of emails). In IMAP folders have subscription and unsubscription, the more folders you have in your outlook email account; more time it will take to sync. Sync of mail client always keep-on syncing, that’s the reason email is displayed instantly as it arrives in IMAP. What you can do is, that keep those folders unsubscribed which are not very active and whenever you need those folders, you can subscribe them again.
**How to Subscribe/Unsubscribe folders:**

- Right Click Inbox>>IMAP Folders
- Click Query

It will show the subscription/subscription status of all folders. You can subscribe/unsubscribe as per your need.

- Click Apply
- Press OK

Now last: Changing account names.

5. Multiple accounts in Outlook are showing email address as an account
   name on left pane of Home tab.

Follow below steps in Outlook.

- Go to File > Options > Advanced > Click on Send/Receive…
- Press the Edit.
- Select your Outlook.com/Hotmail account on the left.
- Press the Account Properties.
- Type the display name for your account on the General tab.

See full detail from [how-to-rename-mailbox-display-name-in-outlook-2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-rename-mailbox-display-name-in-outlook-2016/4d63be01-acd5-4b31-b228-9c1a829a7182).

Answer (score 1):

If you use outlook, consider to connect to workmail via microsoft protocols, which will give you a much better user experience (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/outlook-start.html)